# Spring не видит параметров в URI/ VK API Callback

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

После того как API VK Отдает колбек на мой метод /vk/callback, Spring не видит параметров после **#**

Но токен приходит:

> http://localhost:8080/vk/callback#access_token=token&expires_in=86400&user_id=id

вот в таком формаре. 
**@RequestParam** так же не видит параметра **acceess_token**, а в **Parameter_Map** *HttpServletResponse* лежит null.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "callback")
public String callback(ServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getParameter("access_token");
    System.out.print(token);
    return token;
}
```

Как мне получить эти параметры?